# Find the commits not coming from a "pull request"

Tags: git, pull-request

Not being "pull request" something standard from git it is widely used as a good practice and it is used by default but .... I have an utility that generates documentation based on the fact all the changes that are deployed "come" from a pull request and I am wondering if there is an easy way to detect situations where that's not the case, where commits have been committed directly to "master"

For example in a diagram like that:

```
*    c1 (pull request)
|\
| *  c2
| *  c3
*/
|
*    c4
|
```

I would like to be able to detect c4.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you cant lookup if the commit is in another branch. A branch is just a pointer to a certain commit. So if you delete a branch this pointer is lost. Commits dont know the branch only parent and child (maybe its more complex but lets start with this)

So my wild guess is as long as the original branches exists and are not deleted you can compare commits in master with other branches.

But if the other branches are deleted you will get an high number of false postive. Will try to take a look at home.

Comment: PR has different implementation depending on the platform you are working on (plain Git core tools, GitHub, GitLab, Gerrit, ...). You need to provide more details.

Comment: I use pull request just as an example of merge but the question is about detecting those commits that are "direct commit" without coming from a merged branch. 

I can not check it they are in another branch because once merged the branches are removed... 

Not sure if my question has "sense" it is just I see it is possible at least if you take a look to the graphical representation (at least in a simple case :-)) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this graph

```
*       f484d1c 2020-02-29 (HEAD -> master)
|\
| *     e618633 2020-02-29 (tag: tag_b2, b2)
* |     d141ac2 2020-02-29
|/
*       5072a40 2020-02-29
|\
| *     e9446d3 2020-02-29 (tag: tag_b1, b1)
* |     9508020 2020-02-29 (tag: tag_m2)
|/
*       8bd3257 2020-02-29 (tag: tag_m1)
```

Get the "direct" children (not from merge)

```
git log --first-parent --pretty=format:"%h" tag_m1..HEAD
f484d1c
d141ac2
5072a40
9508020
```

Now get all the commits

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h" tag_m1..HEAD
f484d1c
d141ac2
e618633
5072a40
9508020
e9446d3
```

If we compare both results (eg. with comm) we can get the commits